# Why doesn't this CSS center the `div` element?

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't this CSS center the container `div`?

The JSFiddle is here (ignore the random JQuery):

http://jsfiddle.net/evamvid/7SW3L/20/

Here's the "preview":

[jsfiddle.net/evamvid/7SW3L/20/embedded/result/](http://goo.gl/PG84ik)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it doesn't have a defined width (and is 100% wide by default so it is centered).

You can either explicitly set the width to be the width of the blocks combined, or you can set the `.container` to `inline-block` and have it's container use `text-align: center`.

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/7SW3L/27/)**

Note:  I've put `text-align: center` on the `body` for demo purposes.  In reality, I'd suggest adding another container `<div>` so you don't have your entire body text-aligned to the center.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using `display: block`, you can use `text-align:center;` to center the elements

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7SW3L/21/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just give width to the div. Calculate the total width it will take for the inner boxes and set the with to the div.
If you dont want to give it a width then search for the Table layout options for div.

```
.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 759px;
}
```

Just check this jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/shinde87sagar/7SW3L/26/

Comment: What if the width is variable?

Comment: For variable width U can use the table layout option. Let me get a fiddle for it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shinde87sagar/9bYFk/   Check this fiddle. I have used display: table attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not happening because you have not given width to `.container`. By default, `div` takes 100% width. You need to either give width to `.container` or give it `text-align:center` as inside `.container` your divs are inline.

[**DEMO using width here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7SW3L/32/)

[**DEMO using center here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7SW3L/33/)

Answer (score 0):

[YOUR EXAMPLE REVISED HERE * <sup>Read my comments</sup>](http://jsfiddle.net/7SW3L/36/)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7SW3L/29/)**

You had some issues:

```
.container{
  width:758px;        /* Set a width */
  /* display:block */ /* DIVs ARE ALREADY BLOCK LEVEL ELEMENTS */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or simply use

```
.container{
  text-align:center;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7SW3L/34/)**

Comment: What if the width is variable?

Comment: @evamvid I don't know what you're up to, but I revised a bit your code http://jsfiddle.net/7SW3L/36/ also note if you're going to add margin to your elements, subtract them from jQuery and also you'll need a `$(window).resize` handler to follow up with the sizes change upon resize...

Answer (score 0):

Add following.

```
.container{
 text-align: center;
}
```